# jquery ajax simple form must show the form along with additional content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so i started using jquery with ajax.. all is good..The form is submitted.. but after the response the form disappears and only the output is on screen.. i tried

```
success: function(html)
     {
    $(".result").html(html);
      }
```

i used the show options,but my form doesn't come back..

```
$('#myform').show()
```

what must i do, to display the current div and additional div(after ajax success).. 
hope am clear with this..
Any help appreciated...
And big huge thanks to all members of SO of helping poor newbiess like me.. Thanks in advance..
my code
my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form1").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    passwordid:"required",
    username:"required",
    password_again :"required",
    password_again:{
      equalTo: "#passwordid"
    },
     email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    }
   },
   messages: {

    email: "Please enter your valid email address.",
    username: "Please enter your username",
    passwordid:"Enter Password",
    password_again:"Please enter the same value",
   },
   submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "new.php",
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".result").html(html);



 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**My long form:**

```
//my result class
<div class="result"><div>
<div id="wrapper">


<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
<b> Create New Account </b><br><br><br>

<label for="username" id="username_label">Username</label><br>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username"/><br>

<label for="passwordid" id="password_label">Password</label><br>
<br>    <input   type="password" name="passwordid" id="passwordid" size="35">
<br><br>
<label for="password_again" id="password_again_label">Re-Type Password</label><br>
<br><input   type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again" size="35">
<br>
<b>Personal Details</b><br><br>

<label class="r" for="firstname" id="firstname_label">First Name<br>
<input   type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="35"></label><br><br>

<label class="r" for="lastname" id="lastname_label">Last Name<br>
<input   type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="35"></label><br><br>

Gender<br><br>
<select class="cc" name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Gender--</option>
<option value="m">Male</option>
<option value="f">Female</option>
</select>

<br><br>
Date of birth<br>

<label class="dob" for="dateid" id="date_label">Date
<?php $number = range(1,31);
$tempholder = range(1,31);
$nr=31;
echo '<select class="doba" name="dateid" id="dateid">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Date--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{

        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>
</label>


<label class="dob" for="month" id="month_label">Month
<?php $number = range(1,12);
$tempholder = range(1,12);
$nr=12;
echo '<select class="doba" name="month" id="month">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Month--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{

        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>
</label>

<label class="dob" for="year" id="year_label">Year
<?php 
$tempholder =  range(1960,2000);
$nr=40;
echo '  <select  class="doba" name="year" id="year">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Year--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{
        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>
</label>
<br><br><br><br>
<b>Contact Details</b> <br><br>
<label for="add1" id="add1_label">Address1</label><br>
<input id="add1" type="text" name="add1"/><br>

<label for="add2" id="add2_label">Address2</label><br>
<input id="add2" type="text" name="add2"/><br>

<label for="add3" id="add3_label">Address3</label><br>
<input id="add3" type="text" name="add3"/><br>

<label for="mobile" id="mobile_label">Mobile</label><br>
<input id="mobile" type="text" name="mobile"/><br>

<label for="tele" id="tele_label">Telephone</label><br>
<input id="tele" type="text" name="tele"/><br>

<label for="email" id="email_label">E-mail</label><br>
<input id="email" type="text" name="email"/><br>

<br>


<b>Card Details</b><br><br>
<label for="cardno" id="cardno_label">Card No</label><br>
<input id="cardno" type="text" name="cardno"/><br>

<label for="cvcno" id="cvcno_label">CVC No</label><br>
<input id="cvcno" type="text" name="cvcno"/><br>




<br>
<select  name="cardtype" id="cardtype">
<option value="" selected="selected">--Card Type--</option>
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
<option value="master">Master</option>
<option value="american">American Express</option>
</select><br><br>

Expiry Date<br><br>

<label class="dob" for="dateid1" id="date_label">Date
<?php $number = range(1,31);
$tempholder = range(1,31);
$nr=31;
echo '<select class="doba" name="dateid1" id="dateid1">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Date--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{

        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>

</label>


<label class="dob" for="month1" id="month_label">Month
<?php $number = range(1,12);
$tempholder = range(1,12);
$nr=12;
echo '<select class="doba" name="month1" id="month1">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Month--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{

        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>
</label>

<label class="dob" for="year1" id="year_label">Year
<?php 
$tempholder =  range(2013,2053);
$nr=40;
echo '  <select  class="doba" name="year1" id="year1">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select Year--</option>';
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++)
{
        echo "<option>".$tempholder[$i]."</option>";
        }
    echo '</select>';

?>
</label>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" class="ss" value="SUBMIT" class="left" >


</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML/JavaScript code? Is there any elements inside your form with CSS class "result"?

Comment: no it is empty div..with no content..

Comment: it tried placing the class result in and out of the form.. but no effects.. inside the form the result was not displayed.. outside the form id, it displayed..

Comment: Can I see the full code?

Comment: @Amit the data is sent and recieved.. i check with firebug.. it just with displayin the div items i have problem.. any idea??? vvv helpful..thanks for ur interest..

Comment: How you are hiding the form? using $('#form1').hide(). Also, I did not see $('#form1').show() under your success callback function

Comment: i tried but that didn't work.. i tried #('show') also, that didn't help either...

Comment: i am not hiding any thing in html page.. just want my form to be present along with additional output after ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just and idea, but you can try

```
    $(".result").append(html);
```

instead. .html may be be wiping out your html somehow.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :).. but this result div, even though i placed the div above all, it displays below, maybe because of the usage of append word.. i want it to be in the same location.. any other alternative will be also useful.. thanks again...

Comment: you may want to make to make sure that your html and divs are properly coded. when you run $(".result").html(html); it should only replace the html inside of that .result div. But, it's leaking out somewhere. You can make sure that .result is either 'inside of' or 'outside' of your form. Then, .html should have no effect on the rest of your code.